# How to choose correct trigonometric identity when solving integration questions

Tags: indefinite-integrals

For example
$\int\frac{sin²x}{1+cosx}$dx

Here I use trigonometric identity:-

sin²x= 1-cos²x

The following integral transforms into

$\int\frac{1-cos²x}{1+cosx}$dx

And now here I have another doubt what kind of substitution should I make?

I always struggle with trigonometric integrals.If you have tips for solving trigonometric integrals please tell me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hint: $1-cos^2 x=(1-cos x)(1+cos x)$.

Comment: Full explanation?

Comment: $\int \frac{(1-cosx)(1+cosx)}{1+cosx}\,dx=\int 1-cosx \,dx=x-sinx+c$

Comment: Ahh I got it , actually I see this after commenting but thanks